# Excel Macro - How to change tab color based on cell in a separate worksheet in same workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I tried the following and it doesn't work - any other suggestions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
MyVal = Range("'Summary'!A8").Text

With ActiveSheet.Tab
    Select Case MyVal
        Case "Black"
            .Color = vbBlack
        Case "Red"
            .Color = vbRed
        Case "Green"
            .Color = vbGreen
        Case "Yellow"
            .Color = vbYellow
        Case "Blue"
            .Color = vbBlue
        Case "Magenta"
            .Color = vbMagenta
        Case "Cyan"
            .Color = vbCyan
        Case "White"
            .Color = vbWhite
        Case Else
            .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very helpful. What happens - an error, nothing, ... ? You also need to clarify where this code is and which sheet tab should be coloured.

Comment: I just ran a similar code and the code seemed to work fine. Only difference is that I removed your `MyVal` declaration and changed the `Select` statement to: `Select Case Sheets("Summary").Range("A8").Value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyVal$
MyVal = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A8")

With ActiveSheet.Tab
    Select Case MyVal
        Case "Black"
            .Color = vbBlack
        Case "Red"
            .Color = vbRed
        Case "Green"
            .Color = vbGreen
        Case "Yellow"
            .Color = vbYellow
        Case "Blue"
            .Color = vbBlue
        Case "Magenta"
            .Color = vbMagenta
        Case "Cyan"
            .Color = vbCyan
        Case "White"
            .Color = vbWhite
        Case Else
            .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```